# In react HTML attributes, how to target *this* instance of a component in data-target?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

Using bootstrap in reactJS, say you have a component in which:

```
<div data-target=".foo">
.
.
.
<div class="foo">
```

If there are multiple instances of this component, the data-target attributes hits **all** of the classes "foo" from all the instances. Is it possible to select only *this* component instance?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is same as targeting in HTML. So one way to handle this would be to target a specific Id with `#` instead of the catch all `.`

Comment: I tried that, but when that happens, only the first instance is given the ID, so the data-target always targets the first instance, regardless of which one it is called from